# Toggle classname onclick JavaScript

Tags: javascript, toggle

I am nearly there, just a little unsure as to my code setup, I basically want to remove a class on click, and add it back again onclick, then remove onclick, then add onclick. And so on! Here's what I have, it's nearly there, but if there is a nicer way to do this then please help! Thank you.

```
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function() {
    myButton.className = myButton.className.replace(/(?:^|\s)active(?!\S)/g, '') ? 'active': jbar.className.replace(/(?:^|\s)active(?!\S)/g, '') ;
}
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to use a ternary operator, use this:

```
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function() {

    var className = ' ' + myButton.className + ' ';

    this.className = ~className.indexOf(' active ') ?
                         className.replace(' active ', ' ') :
                         this.className + ' active';
}
```

---

For clarity, I'd use a regular if/else:

```
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function() {

    var className = ' ' + myButton.className + ' ';

    if ( ~className.indexOf(' active ') ) {
        this.className = className.replace(' active ', ' ');
    } else {
        this.className += ' active';
    }              
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ttEGY/

Comment: Brill! Thank you very much. Howcome you didn't need the RegEx?

Comment: @Toddo - Because I wrapped it in spaces, I can just search for an exact string match. Old trick I learnt from the jQuery source.

Comment: Clever, much cleaner than RegEx. Can I trouble you for one extra piece of advice? If I wanted to remove the class from two different divs, at once? How would that be done without writing it twice. Assuming the id is #myButton1 and #myButton2 both containing the class to toggle.

Comment: @Toddo - You can't. You should abstract this functionality into a function, and call it for both elements separately.

Comment: How would you run the function then on each item? or do you mean setup an onclick for each of them?

Comment: Something like this? document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = toggleClass(myButton); with the function above like so: function toggleClass(element) {...}

Comment: @Toddo - Yep. Don't forget to replace `this.className` with `myButton.className`.

Comment: Excellent, but using "className" as a variable name makes the whole block of code somehow confusing on a first sight.

Answer (score 77):

I am *really* surprised nobody mentioned [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) here. So just to be complete: Alternative solution would be to use classList method **toggle()**.

Your case would then simply be:

```
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

e.classList.toggle() has good support (except for, ehm, IE, It's there since IE10). [Click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Browser_compatibility) for complete browser compatibility.

Comment: Why is this not marked as the right answer? Shorter and cleaner than the other answer.

Comment: In 2021, this is definitely the correct answer.  Everyone, please use `classList.toggle(...)`!

Answer (score 2):

If JQuery is okay for you it really is as simple as

```
$(myButton).toggleClass('active')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bikeshedder/eRJB4/

Comment: Thanks, but jQuery is not what I want to use. Cheers anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Suggest common realization of toggleClass method:

```
function toggleClass(element, tClass) {
    tClass = tClass.replace(/\s/g, "");

    var classes =  element.className;
    element.className = classes.indexOf(tClass) !== -1 
        ? classes.replace(" " + tClass, "")
        : classes + " " + tClass;
}
```

using:

```
var element = document.getElementById('myId');
toggleClass(element, 'active');
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementation using Array methods:

```
const toggleClass = (element, className) => {
  let classNames = element.className.split(' ');
  let index = classNames.indexOf(className);
  if (index === -1) {
    classNames.push(className);
  } else {
    classNames.splice(index, 1);
  }
  element.className = classNames.filter(item => item !== '').join(' ');
}
```

Usage:

```
let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
toggleClass(body, 'ready');
```

[Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/3jWU3gva6GJVPUdturaN/)