# javascript function on multiple buttons

Tags: javascript

I have three buttons. I would like them to change colour when pressed, and back to no colour when pressed again.

I found this code on stackoverflow that allows me to almost do it however, it only works on one button, the other two are not affected.
Also, when I pressed one of the other two buttons, the first button changes colour. I tried changing ID's on the buttons, adding another script with different `getElementById()` ID's but nothing works.

Do I need more than one function to achieve what I want?

The code I am using is below.

```js
var count = 1;
function setColor(btn, color) {
  var property = document.getElementById(btn);
  if (count == 0) {
    property.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
    count = 1;
  } else {
    property.style.backgroundColor = "#E68352";
    count = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" id="button" value = "A-D" style= "color:black" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010')";/>
  <input type="button" id="button" value = "E-H" style= "color:black" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010')";/>
  <input type="button" id="button" value = "E-H" style= "color:black" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010')";/>
</body>
```

Comment: IDs should be unique!

Comment: SO I should have three different functions and three buttons with different IDs?

Comment: No. Pass (this) and you have access to the clicked button regardless of ID or class

Comment: No, just one function but call it with different IDs!

Comment: Not exactly duplicate as OP is using `style` instead of `class`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615712/toggle-classname-onclick-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, when you write inline event handler you may take advantage of:

> - [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this): current element:  When code is called from an in–line on-event handler, its this is set to the DOM element on which the listener is placed:
> - [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers): event element object

Therefore, change:

```
onclick="setColor('button', '#101010')"
```

with:

```
onclick="setColor(this, event, '#101010')"
```

So your code can be rewritten as:

```js
function hexToRgb(hex) {
    var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
    return result ? 'rgb(' +
        parseInt(result[1], 16) + ', ' +
        parseInt(result[2], 16) + ', ' +
        parseInt(result[3], 16) + ')'
     : null;
}


function setColor(btnEle, evt, color) {
    if (btnEle.style.backgroundColor == hexToRgb("#E68352")) {
        btnEle.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"
    }
    else {
        btnEle.style.backgroundColor = "#E68352"
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="button1" value = "A-D" style= "color:black" onclick="setColor(this, event, '#101010')";/>
<input type="button" id="button2" value = "E-H" style= "color:black" onclick="setColor(this, event, '#101010')";/>
<input type="button" id="button3" value = "E-H" style= "color:black" onclick="setColor(this, event, '#101010')";/>
```

Comment: Thanks gaetanoM. Lots of good answers but yours was most appropriate for my code and it worked out of the box. And I learned something new. Thanks to everyone else for their answers.

Comment: this is the best and fastest solution! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should have uniques `ID`

You can use `classList.toggle("yourClass")` instead of using a `count`

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
for (let i = 0, l = buttons.length; i < l; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    buttons[i].classList.toggle('active');
  })
}
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: #E68352 !important;
}

.button {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="button1" class="button" value="A-D" />
<input type="button" id="button2" class="button" value="E-H" />
<input type="button" id="button3" class="button" value="E-H" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a class on the buttons, and then loop through the buttons and add an event listener to each of them:

**EDIT**: I see you are using an onclick handler, which I didn't notice at first; so this answer might not be as useful as I thought. You should definitely use different IDs though if you use that approach.

`<button class="button" ... >`

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button')
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Do your button things.
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IDs should be unique inside the document. Like this:

```
<input type="button" id="button1" value="A-D" style="color:black" onclick="setColor('button1', '#101010')" ;/>
<--                       here ^                                                      here ^               -->
<input type="button" id="button2" value="E-H" style="color:black" onclick="setColor('button2', '#101010')" ;/>
<--                       here ^                                                      here ^               -->
<input type="button" id="button3" value="E-H" style="color:black" onclick="setColor('button3', '#101010')" ;/>
<--                       here ^                                                      here ^               -->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    var count = 1;

    function setColor(btn, color) {
      var property = document.getElementById(btn);
      if (count == 0) {
        property.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"
        count = 1;
      } else {
        property.style.backgroundColor = "#E68352"
        count = 0;
      }
    }
  </script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <input type="button" id="button1" value="A-D" style="color:black" onclick="setColor('button1', '#101010')" ;/>
  <input type="button" id="button2" value="E-H" style="color:black" onclick="setColor('button2', '#101010')" ;/>
  <input type="button" id="button3" value="E-H" style="color:black" onclick="setColor('button3', '#101010')" ;/>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need little bit of modification.
See the working code.

```js
function setColor(btn, color) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(btn);

  if (elem.hasAttribute("style")) {
    if (elem.getAttribute("style").indexOf("background-color:") == -1) {
          elem.style.backgroundColor = color;
    } else {
          elem.style.backgroundColor = "";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <input type="button" id="button1" value="A-D" style="color:black" onclick="setColor('button1', '#E68352')" ;/>
  <input type="button" id="button2" value="E-H" style="color:black" onclick="setColor('button2', '#E68352')" ;/>
  <input type="button" id="button3" value="E-H" style="color:black" onclick="setColor('button3', '#E68352')" ;/>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks WitVault, this gets me closer however. after I click button1 and it changes colour, I then have to press button2 twice in order to change colour. Same for button3. The same issue comes up when I want the buttons to change back to no colour.

Comment: @Roberto you were using global variable for the check. Updated the answer please check.

Answer (score 0):

IDs need to be unique but you do not need them here

Give the buttons a class and use toggle the classList

```js
window.onload=function() {
  var buts = document.querySelectorAll(".but");
  for (var i=0;i<buts.length;i++) {
    buts[i].onclick=function() {
      this.classList.toggle("clicked");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.but {background-color:black}
.clicked { background-color:#E68352; }
```

```html
<input type="button" value="A-D" class="but" />
<input type="button" value="E-F" class="but" />
<input type="button" value="G-H" class="but" />
```

Comment: Few seconds faster hehe

Comment: 6 seconds to be precise

Answer (score 0):

dont use numbers, use **this** instead
http://codepen.io/animhotep/pen/qRwjeX?editors=0010

```
var count = 1;

function setColor(btn, color) {
  if (count == 0) {
    btn.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"
    count = 1;
  }
  else {
    btn.style.backgroundColor = "#E68352"
    count = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Roberto, as Ibrahim correctly pointed out, the problem is that you are using the same ID for all buttons. When javascript executes this code:

```
var property = document.getElementById(btw);
```

it will always return the first element with the ID specified. One solution is choosing a different ID for each button and updating the corresponding `onclick` code. Another solution could be the one below, in which you do not need to specify IDs at all and the function `setColor` could be used for any element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var count = 1;
function setColor(element, color) {
    if (count == 0) {
        el.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"
        count = 1;
    }
    else {
        el.style.backgroundColor = "#E68352"
        count = 0;
    }
}
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" value = "A-D" style= "color:black" onclick="setColor(this, '#101010')";/>
    <input type="button" value = "E-H" style= "color:black" onclick="setColor(this, '#101010')";/>
    <input type="button" value = "E-H" style= "color:black" onclick="setColor(this, '#101010')";/>
</body>
</html>
```

Note the use of the `this` variable as the first argument for `setColor`. In each of the buttons, the corresponding `this` will point to the element where it is defined.

Hope it helps.