# Toggle classname onclick using JavaScript: Why does Eclipse complain?

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I used the following codes posted as the accepted answer in [Toggle classname onclick JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615712/toggle-classname-onclick-javascript)

It works great in all browsers, even in old version IE (my project needs this IE support). The only change I made is using this.className instead of myButton.classname in the 2nd line since IE would give error to myButton.classname ('myButton' is undefined).

My question is: even it works, why Eclipse complains by showing a red X beside the last line? If I hover mouse over the red wave under the last } (in the last line), it shows: "Multiple annotations found at this line:   - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody- Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression". This error does occur even if I did not make the above change.

If I add ; after the last } (thinking the function is a part of an executable statement), Eclipse still complains although it continues to work.

Could anyone please give any hints?

```
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function() {

    var className = ' ' + this.className + ' ';

    if ( ~className.indexOf(' active ') ) {
        this.className = className.replace(' active ', ' ');
    } else {
        this.className += ' active';
    }              
}
```

Comment: I don't know why eclipse is telling you this. But I see two issues with the code you posted. The first is the ~ in from on className in the if statement. Maybe a typo or else something I don't understand in JavaScript? The second is the use of className. Maybe this is necessary for IE compatibility, but otherwise I would recommend using classList instead

Comment: @ControlAltDel see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299665/what-does-a-tilde-do-when-it-precedes-an-expression - it's a rather oldfashioned idiom for checking if a number is -1, nowadays you'd just use `className.includes(' active ')`. Agree on the use of `classname` instead of `classList`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! ~ is the tilde operator (https://wsvincent.com/javascript-tilde/) and it serves the purpose in this case. Yes I agree with using classList, but I have to support IE old versions, so className is needed. Also thanks @Robin Zigmond for confirming.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in the current Eclipse. Which Eclipse version do you have? Which JavaScript editor do you use (WTP or WWD) of which version?

Comment: @howlger Thanks for checking! I should have included this info. I am using Eclipse Oxygen.3a (4.7.3a) and WTP JSDT 2.1.1.v201804042202. So you were suggesting this may be an editor issue and I shall update it? Thanks a lot.